# "bootstrap could not be loaded" error on windows ce 5; visual studio 2005; Intermec CK70

Tags: debugging, visual-studio-2005, windows-ce, intermec

I'm encountering this error whenever I debug my program: `The bootstrap could not be loaded` I have been encountering this since I formatted my PC

- Platform: `Windows CE 5.0`
- IDE: `Visual Studio 2005`
- Device: `Intermec CK70`

Thanks!

Comment: Hi I made a small edit to your post, to clarify, you are attempting to debug a program for the `Intermec CK70` with VS 2005, and get that error, do you have any more information that might help someone find an answer?

Comment: @EruPenkman, I've come up with a solution. I used system restore to when my VS2005 is still working. I think there is some kind of conflict between VS2005 and VSCommunity 2013.

Comment: nice work! sorry noone else could help you. Could you please post that as an answer to your own question and accept it

Comment: @EruPenkman, its ok. As your advise, posted the answer and accepted it as the solution. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

System restore to when my VS 2005 runs perfectly, I think VS Community 2013 and VS 2005 is having a conflict. -posted this as an answer as per advised by @EruPenkman